# Page Flipping with mootools

Tags: html, mootools

I need to create a flip effect with *mootools*

I'm trying to make it with Fx.Slide, but the problem is the write transition (Fx.Transition)?

Has anyone some tips?
PS: Hier is a small idea about what i'm talking about ;-)

```
var myTransition = new Fx.Transition(function(pos, x){
                return 1 - Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.log(pos) / Math.log(x && x[0] || Math.E)), pos);
                }, 1.3);

var myFx = new Fx.Slide('singlePage', {
                mode: 'horizontal',
                duration: 1000,
                transition: myTransition.easeOut
                });

 myFx.toggle().chain(myFx.toggle);
```

Comment: Try to edit your question & make it nice formatting.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What did you try so far? Could you perhaps show us your recent approach? Reading and debugging code may be easier then guessing from a rather vague description of the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to make a book viewer with mootools, and for that i need bookPage flip effect writen on mootools; Thanks :)

Comment: are you a patent troll? this is now owned by apple. http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/11/16/apple-now-owns-the-page-turn/ - so any reply here would be infringing (potentially :)

Comment: I dont need to do the same animation what Apple did, i need just a simple slip transition that look like as page flip and not tween to the side, it doesn't look good :(

Comment: And by the way, that was a design patent which, as I understood it, means they own their page turn, not the idea of a **page** **turn** :)